# AWS CDK Python Custom Construct Example

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I am able to write custom constructs easily in Python, but some of the AWS CF objects are only available as L1 Cfn constructs.

Does someone have a good example of adding methods to custom constructs in Python?

Looking at translated code from the Construct Hub is not helping and I can't see to find anyone writing custom constructs with methods. My google skills are failing me.

***For the interested***

No I don't care about submitting to the Construct hub or that functions written in Typescript are great and can be used by polyglot people.

These custom constructs are for me and probably only I will care about them.

Comment: A construct is just a class - so just add methods to your custom class.

Comment: Yeah that hasn't worked for me. Doesn't seem like the object is passing the right context for the created object. Do you have an example?

Comment: You'll need to add some code of your attempts to the question. Apologies for the dumb question, but do you have experience with adding methods to a class?